# import com.google isn't working properly on vsCode

Tags: java, gradle, import

I have recently begun working on a project that requires me to use gson, however, when I try to import the file it says: "The import com.google cannot be resolved" I have already created my build.gradle and I believe I have imported it properly.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'
}

tasks.named('compileJava') {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs += ['-Xlint:none']
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.build {
    dependsOn helloWorldTask
}

// Define the 'helloWorldTask'
task helloWorldTask {
    doFirst {
        java.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += ['src/main/java-import-only']
        java.sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs += ['src/test/java-import-only']

        tasks.named('compileJava') {
            doFirst {
                sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
        }
        tasks.named('compileTestJava') {
            doFirst {
                sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is in the same folder as the file I'm importing gson for, I have already tried restarting VS code.